# Ubuntu 13.10: wpa_supplicant crashes on login

Tags: 13.10, wpa-supplicant

Every time I log in, and sometimes multiple times in a row, I get a error message. I don't seem to have any problems with the functionality of my computer. I'm running ubuntu 13.10 on a google pixel, has a Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 wireless network adapter (not sure if that will matter here).

[Screenshot of error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQbN5.png)

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I get 3 error reporting popups as soon as I log in and then this same message about an internal error.  I'm also on amd64.

Comment: Great! Work`s on! I install using the command line mode only. It`s bettet

Answer (score 5):

Running this command fixed the problem for me

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp`

Note: after running this command, my custom keyboard shortcuts seem to have been reset.